# What is the way to get count of tweets with perticular keyword (# tag) from twitter?

Tags: twitter, social-networking, tweets

I need to organize images of trending people on twitter, and i need to dynamically update position of images accordingly...

Comment: Can you give more details please? I can't really understand what exactly you are trying to achieve. Are these the profile images for instance? And if so how are you organizing them ? Is it a social network graph ? What exactly are you measuring for edge weights if that is the case etc.

Comment: Hi, Actually i have images(static) of 5 sports men, I want to display those images in order of there hashtag count (eg: #TigerWood) on twitter. I want realtime(without page post back) data of count of all 5 images and need to sort according to it.